# Fluid from Sphere keeps falling from previous position

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I am having this problem in Blender 2.93 and 3.0. The fluid from sphere keeps falling from its first position from where simulation was run first time, even when I have changed the position of sphere, fluid keeps coming from that first position. Why is that ? How to remedy this ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: hello, maybe you need to recalculate the Bake?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @moonboots even after recalculating the bake, the fluid still keeps falling from where Sphere used to be. Only way this stops happening is if I delete the domain cube and re-add it and re-set the settings, and only then the fluid falls from new position of sphere. I there any way of avoiding this deletion-addition of domain cube ?  I feel most of settings dont even take place in Blender, not sure if its some cache issue or what.

Comment: Maybe share your file so that we can take a look at it (only keep the domain + inflow): https://pasteall.org/blend/ ... Maybe there are some bugs in fluids though

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/d18c6b2fe7554b559eac11f7162c07bb In this file, atm even in Eevee mode, the flow is not coming out now. Unless I delete Domain and re-add it then it works. Basically, it seems that for every change, I will have to delete and add domain again

Comment: Never mind, I just tried varying the resolution of liquid sphere and that essentially resets the previous settings, hence now no need to delete and re-add the cube.